# Curl Post Command in Linux with header

Tags: json, linux, curl

I need to hit a JSON URL with POST method with header AND VALUE.

Below is the command I passed with out header

```
curl -X POST "URL" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Now I need to pass header value along with this:

`user_id` is the header name and value is user how should i pass it?

Can anyone please help

Comment: You are already passing Content-Type in header. -H switch adds stuff  to header. Why not use another -H switch? curl -X POST "URL" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "user_id: value"

Comment: What is a "JSON URL"? What do you mean by "header", an HTTP header?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.